# ScrollSpy feature of Bootstrap 5 not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use scroll-spy feature of bootstrap 5 to ensure that the corresponding navbar item is shown active when I scroll through those sections of the html page. however I see its not working for me. The navigation-link item becomes inactive the moment I remove the cursor over it. Below are the snippets of my code:

I am trying to use data-bs-spy on the body tag. Below is the structure of my code

```
<body data-bs-spy="scroll data-bs-target="#nav-example" data-bs-offset="0"  tabindex="0">
<header id="nav-items">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="nav-example">
  
  <div id="navItem">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nav-items">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Section1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">
            Section2
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
        </a>
      
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  
  </div>
</nav>
</header>
<section id="home">...</section>
<section id="Section1">....</section>
<section id="Section2">....</section>
<section id="Section3">....</section
</body>
```

and here is the relevant CSS for this.

```
body{
    position:relative;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#navItem>ul>li> a{
    display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

#navItem>ul>li> a:hover{
    color: red;
}

#navItem>ul>li> a:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  
  }
  
  #navItem>ul>li a:hover:before , #navItem>ul>li a:active:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
```

[Complete Working code](https://www.codeply.com/p/NmuwHllAN8)

Comment: In your "Complete working code" link, there's missing a quote after scroll: `data-bs-spy="scroll"`. (line 12) Seems to work if you add it

Comment: Thanks @StephanBauer. Though i see it working, i see the menu item does not has the underline feature. I want the menu to be underlined too when i scroll through the corresponding section. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your active menu item underlined, you can add `#navItem>ul>li a.active:before,` to the following rule :

```
#navItem>ul>li a:hover:before , #navItem>ul>li a:active:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: thanks. it worked